# Scale instance to exact curve length

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have geometry with multiple curve elements. I need to scale the instance to the length of the curve that it sits on. Each curve is not all equal in length so the instance scaling has to work according to the curves length.

How can I translate the curve length to the scale of the cube so that it is all the same distances when it meets at the respective points?

[image]**Blender File**

[image: As you can see the Value node controls the distance away from the point.]

[image: As I scale the instance it does not respect the curve length]

[image: When you increase the scale of the cube you can see they do not meet evenly at the center]

Answer (score 6):

That can be the following:

[image]

Delete faces, split edges, convert to curve.

Make a cube with a given X/Y sizes and 1 unit in Z. Shift it half its height.

Instance on points with only first points of the curve.

Align cube Z to the curve tangent.

Scale on Z with the spline length.

Comment: Champion! Thank you so so much!!!!!!!!!! Elegant and simple. WOW